Auto-Number Using a specific format and using an already existing field as the base (workflow loop?)
I have an opportunity field called Order # that the user enters it in this format 24-022.  I'd like to use this Order # and add a -1, -2, -3 etc. to the end (example 24-022-1) and this field will be called BOL # for each new quote created.  I'd like to have first quote created will have the field BOL # auto populate to 24-022-1 and the second quote created will have the field BOL # auto populate to 24-022-2 and so on.
I've tried to concatenate the Order # field and a new field with "-1" in it.  It works, but it can't create the next one to be "-2" and then "-3" and so on.  And then I'd like those numbers to start over when in a different opportunity (and different Order #).
I've been told that I can create a loop workflow to achieve this, but I cannot seem to figure it out.  Any help is appreciated.

As I understand your enquiry, you need to add the sort of number postfix to the Quote BOL#, so you can!
Enter the Salesforce Record-Triggered Flows. To create one - enter Setup -> Object Manager -> Quote and find the "Flow Triggers" in the sidebar, select and click "New Flow" in the top right.
Now, specify the Flow entry: Object - Quote, Event - A record is created, Condition Requirements - None, Optimize the Flow for - Fast Field Updates
Then, you need to query all quotes that are added to this opportunity, count them and add assign the result to the Quote field.
The components

Query records, set object Quote, criteria Opportunity Id EQUALS $Record.OpportunityId, call it "Query related Quotes"
Assignment, create a variable to store the count of the Quotes, call it var_QuoteCount, use it in the assignment like var_QuoteCount EQUALS COUNT "Query related Quotes"
Assignment, create a formula for the new number template, call it fml_QuoteBol, type Text, formula: {!$Record.Opportunity.OrderNumber} & '-' & LPAD(TEXT({!var_QuoteCount}+1), 2 , '0'). LPAD helps to add leading zeroes




THE LAST BUT NOT LEAST - DRAWBACKS

If you have many quotes, it could be a bad solution because you always query all quotes from the related opportunity. It could be better to query the last record but it demands more logic to increase the number

If you are inserting multiple Quotes at a time the flow will fill all of them with the same number because it works with all quotes at the moment under the hood, and it's impossible to look under it in flows.



Just adding to the second drawback, it might be worth clarifying that more. This would only be an issue if you were inserting multiple Quotes for the same Opportunity at the same time, not a bulk load of Quotes across different Opportunities. A trigger would likely have much of the same issues with that however, as you'd still not be sure which quote should get which pre-fix in that scenario.

It worked! Thank you so much!  I have 3 different quote record types.  I'd like this flow to only count the record type entitled "Bill of Lading".  Do you have a suggestion for how to do that?

@LisaWalters you can include the Record Type as an additional filter in the Get Records node so that it only retrieves those that you want to include. You can do the same thing for other criteria you need, for example you wanted to exclude draft or discarded quotes.
